# Returning loop results in multiple dataframe

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a data of 4 years but I want to get a data of a spesific periods and store them in different dataframes.
For instance, I want to get data of one month before these dates:
month_1 = 2023-04-25
month_2 = 2023-03-25
And then save the results in df_1 for month_1 and df_2 for month_2.

In other words, df_1 will store data from 2023-03-25 to 2023-04-25 and
df_2 will store data from 2023-02-25 to 2023-03-25.

I've tried to use 'for' loop with this code:

```
#months of interest
date_col = month_1, month_2

for d in date_col:
  date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d')
  starttime = (date + relativedelta(months=-1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  endtime = (date + relativedelta(months=0)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

  print('STARTTIME' + ' '+ starttime)
  print('ENDTIME' + ' '+ endtime)

  Current_month_resign_emp = spark.sql("""
    SELECT *
    FROM Table_resignation_emp
    WHERE record_update >= '{0}' AND record_update <= '{1}'
    """.format(starttime, endtime))
```

From the code above, the loop seems running sucessfully.

[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx5Th.png)

But, I don't know how to return and save the results in different dataframe.

I tried this

```
#months of interest
date_col = month_1, month_2
result_month = {}

for d in date_col:
  date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d')
  starttime = (date + relativedelta(months=-1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  endtime = (date + relativedelta(months=0)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

  print('STARTTIME' + ' '+ starttime)
  print('ENDTIME' + ' '+ endtime)

  Current_month_resign_emp = spark.sql("""
    SELECT *
    FROM Table_resignation_emp
    WHERE record_update >= '{0}' AND record_update <= '{1}'
    """.format(starttime, endtime))
  result_month.append(Current_month_resign_emp)

  Current_month_resign_emp[d] = pd.DataFrame(Current_month_resign_emp)

print(result_month)
```

But, I got this error message

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTuco.png)

I'd really appreciate any correction or input.
Thank you!

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. `append()`  cannot be used with `dict`, you can use `update()` or give a `key : value` pair to add to the dict. If you want to `append()` then you should use a `list`

Comment: Try this `result_month[d] = pd.DataFrame(Current_month_resign_emp)`. This will create dictionary having current month resign as dataframe. To access just loop through the months of interest and `result_month[d]` code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code according to your data.

```
date_col  = [1,2,3] <Your month interest>
result_month  = {}

for  d  in  date_col:
    df  =  pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\v-jgs\Desktop\ml\python\source1_data.csv")
    result_month[d] =  df
    
for  d  in  date_col:
    print(result_month[d].shape)
    
print(result_month)
```

Here I am directly reading the csv file as pandas dataframe, you use the conversion and store it in result month as shown.

Below is the output.

[image]

Comment: yeah. tell me if that works or not.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the answer! I tried it and it worked. Another question: what should I do with the code if I want to save each dataframes into pyspark dataframe? Is it possible?

Comment: `result_month[d] = pd.DataFrame(Current_month_resign_emp)` here you are converting spark df to pandas df. Just don't convert it.